# Change isolation level in records query or close transaction

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mysql-python, python-records

I'm trying to build some autotest scripts using [Kenneth Reitz's records library](https://github.com/kennethreitz/records/). I need to check the MySQL database for updates here and there.

```
db_url_mysql = 'mysql://user:pass@mysql.localhost:3306/DB'
db = records.Database(db_url_mysql)
rows = db.query("SELECT * FROM Users").all()
```

However, I encountered that sometimes simple queries return an empty dataset, ignoring updates in tables. I could totally see the updates in GUI clients or even using records in alternative python console.
I found that records use SQLAlchemy with default isolation level "REPEATABLE READ". Repeatable reads ignore all updates until an end of the transaction, so I could not see them.

Is there any way I can change that? I probably need to close a transaction and open a new one, or perhaps change isolation level for this connection, but how can I do it?

Comment: I still could not find a way to change this setting without dropping records library and moving to SQLAlchemy. However, I found a workaround. If you call `db.query('SET AUTOCOMMIT=1')` , next queries will be committed as soon as called, effectively allowing you to check your db without caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I can answer to my question.

With the release of records 0.5.0 (Novemmber 2016) there is now a possibility to pass arguments to SQLAlchemy driver. There was no such possibility in 0.4.3 which I used.

So, to set up isolation level on connection we should use

```
db_url_mysql = 'mysql://user:pass@mysql.localhost:3306/DB'
db = records.Database(db_url_mysql,isolation_level="READ_UNCOMMITTED")
```